# Newest Web2Py & Pycharm Debugger not compatible?

Tags: debugging, pycharm, web2py

I just created a new Web2Py project from the Github source 
    (git clone --recursive https://github.com/web2py/web2py.git).
While I was working on the project I noticed that my debugger is not working on my own controllers.

It works whenever I put a breakpoint in the db.py but as soon as one is in my own controllers it stops working. The page just gets loaded instantly and PyCharm behaves like normal.

I have ran & debugged multiple web2py projects before this and have updated to the latest version.

Anyone who has encountered similar problems or any clue on a fix?

Edit: I migrated the the project to an old web2py version, now the debugger works. Anyone with an answer as too why would be a genius.

Project Configuration:
[image]

Console output while running page:
[image]

Comment: I have an similar issue with the newest versión of PyDAL, using Eclipse Mars 2 Release (4.5.2) with Pydev 4.5.5 ., i have merged my project Web2py/PyDAL to the last version, this causes the debug breakpoints does not work never more, if i return PYDAL to my previous commit, the breakpoints work again, then seems to be a problem with the new versión of PyDAL.

Comment: I have the same problem just now, but even in old releases of DAL, this is happening. Very odd and annoying.